# Objects not valid issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have the following component that is a lot like the React.js main tutorial. Basically, I have an api that I'm pulling from and trying to load the data:

```
var Box = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function () {
      return {
        data: {
          items: []
       }
      };
   },
   loadStuffFromServer: function() {
      $.ajax({
         url: this.props.url,
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data: data});
         }.bind(this),
         error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
         }.bind(this)
     });
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadStuffFromServer();
  },
  render: function() {
    var blah = this.state.data;
    return (
       <div>
           { blah }
       </div>
    );
  }
});
```

However when I put blah there, I get the error: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {items}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of`Box`.`

I call my component with react rails and `<%= react_component('Box',url: "URLHERE", pollInterval: 1000) %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array` (`data.items`)  instead of `Object`

```
var blah = this.state.data.items;
__________________________^^^^^^___


render: function () {
   var blah = this.state.data.items.map(function (item) {
     return <p>
       { item.content }
     </p>;
   });

   return <div>
     { blah }
   </div>;
}
```

Comment: @the_ I've created small example https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/25289/, you need there only add ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Alexander said, you don't have to assign state's value to a variable. You can directly do- inside the div tag

```
<div> { this.state.data.items } <div>
```

And Use a .map to get the values.

```
{this.state.data.items.map(objval =>
  <div>
   {objval.name}
  </div>
)}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't fix the issue?